# What does WidgetsBinding.instance?.addObserver(this) does exactly?

Tags: flutter, dart, android-widget

Are we adding a listener to the instance of widgetbinding that would listen to lifecycle event in our app? how is WidgetBindingObserver class helping here exactly, could someone please explain me?

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with WidgetsBindingObserver{

  @override
  void initState() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance?.addObserver(this); // <--
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    print(state.name);
    super.didChangeAppLifecycleState(state);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance?.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With "WidgetBindingObserver", you can listen to the behavior of your phone to the application you made. So, what states can I listen to? The answer to this is better explained in the docs.

Also, I'll give you an example, So, you think bank applications, when you open task manager on your phone, application states will be blocked with opaque.
In order to do that, you have to listen to these situations.

Document: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/AppLifecycleState.html